# Is "None of them noticed a large, tawny owl flutter past the window." correct?

Tags: word-usage

> None of them noticed a large, tawny owl **flutter** past the window.

I saw this sentence in the book *Harry Potter*. I think the sentence should be written as:

> 1. None of them noticed a large, tawny owl **fluttered** past the window.
> 2. None of them noticed a large, tawny owl **fluttering** past the window.

The first one takes "a large, tawny owl **fluttered** past the window." as a full clause with the past tense applied. And the second one takes **fluttering** as a present participle describing **owl**.

Did I get something wrong there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

verbs of sensation:

She saw him *run* <sup>infintive</sup>

She saw him *running*. <sup>participle</sup>

She saw *he ran*. <sup>reduced clause with finite verb</sup>

Comment: Ok, so all are correct forms then?

Comment: @dan: **noticed an owl flutter** is the infinitive form.

Comment: Are the other two sentences I made correct too? I think all of three sentences mean the same.

Comment: They don't mean *exactly* the same thing. There is an aspectual difference between **fluttered** and **fluttering**. They're all grammatical, though I think we'd normally find ***that* a large, tawny owl fluttered**, FWIW.  The weightier the finite subordinate clause, the more likely it is to be introduced with *that*. But that's just a tendency, not a requirement.  And the past perfect there, **had fluttered**, would be an improvement, IMO.